# YTPlayerView not working properly

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have embedded YouTube in my application using YTPlayerView helper library for iOS the main issue I am facing right now is that I have embedded the multiple instances of YTPlayerView within scrollview and its loosing its not calling the `changestate` playback properly. The problem occurs when two videos are loaded concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use multiple instance of ytplayer in same view as it described in this link 
[see here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

- The library does not support concurrent video playback in multiple
  YTPlayerView instances. If your application has multiple YTPlayerView
  instances, a recommended best practice is to pause or stop playback
  in any existing instances before starting playback in a different
  instance. In the example application that ships with the project, the
  ViewControllers make use of NSNotificationCenter to dispatch
  notifications that playback is about to begin. Other ViewControllers
  are notified and will pause playback in their YTPlayerView instances.

Comment: I am doing the same thing you have mentioned to handle the playback but and also handling the delegate but still the problem is there

Comment: are you using two ytplayer in the same view?if so you cant use 2 ytplayers i tested by myself if you have 2 ytplayers in same view then you have to pause or stop one of them and play or resume another one....

Comment: if you want to achieve multiple ytplayer you can nest uiviewcontroller and handle individual ytplayers you can use this method to nest viewcontroller addChildViewController:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:

Comment: no thats not what I am doing ,I am actually nesting the controller

Comment: are you handling ytplayers in individual child controllers?that should work

Comment: well i tried to use multiple ytplayer adding chiled VC but not working well i can suggest you a way but it may lead to hard code. You can have an another uiwebview and play using iframe on html. you may implement your logic as your requirements. Refer to this link https://www.developerfeed.com/how-embed-youtube-video-uiview-iphone/. Yeah using uiwebview youtube videos may not load in simulater but works perfect in device hope this helps

Comment: another solution is you can use MPMoviePlayerController